# Windows 10 - Have to run calc/Calculator twice from the Run menu

Tags: windows-10, calculator

I use Calculator in Windows 10 every once in a while. However, I'm facing an odd issue when launching it.

**Short version**
I often have to execute `calc` twice from the Run menu before Calculator shows up.

**Long version**
I always launch Calculator by typing `calc` in the Run menu, which has never been a problem for me on previous versions of Windows. In Windows 10, however, nothing appears to be happening when I run it the first time. If I open Task Manager, I can see that Calculator is listed under Background processes, but it doesn't show up. If I go to the App history tab, right-click Calculator and select Switch to, Calculator shows up twice. If I instead open the Run menu and run `calc` again, it shows up once as expected.

From this point on, I can launch Calculator just fine from the Run menu, until I haven't used it for a period of time. Then it's the same thing all over again.

Has anyone else experienced this, and if so, did you find a fix for it? I've found a couple of threads on Reddit with users complaining about this issue, but no solution so far.

**Update:** This appears to have been fixed. I have not had this problem for the past few weeks, but I have been unable to find any details on the update that fixed this.

Comment: Same for me, I can fix it by executing _calc_ again.

Comment: @Kimmax That's what I do as well (as mentioned in my question), but it's still annoying that you have to run it twice to open Calculator.

Comment: Both `calc` and `calculator://` seem to work fine for me on every try. Keep a task manager window on with `Details` tab open and see if it appears every time you type it and then disappears.

Comment: @Chirag64 Calculator.exe was already shown on the Details tab with a status of **Suspended**. When I run `calc` from the Run menu it changes to **Running**, but it doesn't show up. If I don't run `calc` again within a few seconds, it goes back to **Suspended**.

Answer (score 0):

Run "calculator://" instead of "calc". "calc" is in Windows 10 just a wrapper, and it's seems that it doesn't work all the time

Comment: I'm not on Windows, but are you sure it's `caluculator://`, not just `calculator`?

Comment: I've already read about this and tried running `calculator://` several times, but the result is the same unfortunately.

Comment: @Arjan `calculator://` is a protocol that will open the protocol handler (default calc.exe). OTOH `calc` will always run calc.exe. You need to enter it in an address bar like in Explorer's, or in run dialog (Win+R)

Comment: @phuclv, nice, I'm now making all my websites trigger the `calculator://` protocol when seeing IE or Edge being used! ;-)

Comment: @Arjan that also works in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: I think the point is that he wants to punish those using MS browsers ;-)